# Increasing general AWS console timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

The AWS console appears to kick you out after 24-hours, and I'd like to increase it slightly. This has nothing to do with SSO. Is this a fundamental requirement or can it be tweaked somewhere?

Comment: I have never come across a way to do that. 24 hours is fairly long, some standards like PCI specify a 15 minute timeout.

Comment: And in such systems, it'd be non-compliant by default. So, configurability would be convenient in both directions. In my case, it's just a regular annoyance to a development workflow. It might technically be every twenty-four hours, but it seems like every time I turn around I'm getting challenged again and this primarily only affects me at present.

Comment: Yep. You can change session times for roles, but not for IAM users AFAIK. If no-one here can answer the question I can put a low priority support case into AWS to ask.

Comment: So I can just tweak the roles without getting into SSO? Have a link?

Comment: Are you logging with AWS SSO or AWS IAM? If you log in with IAM your user will be kicked out anyway. SSO is different, haven't used it in a while. From memory you just go into the role in IAM and change the setting called something like timeout or session length.

Comment: Just IAM. Okay.